# Turning OFF the airplane mode causing application to get killed by Android OS

Tags: android

When my application is on the foreground and I am on any screen of the application, I turn ON the flight mode by pulling down the notification bar and after few seconds I turn the airplane  mode OFF again.

As soon as I turn the airplane mode OFF after few second the os kills my application. It doesn't through any exception in the LogCat. It goes through onPause()/onDestroy()  and I can put a break point in the onPause() and onDestroy() methods and it stops there. But I am not able to find out the cause.

If any one has seen the scenario or let me know the approach to find out what causing it, I would appreciate it.

OS Version: 4.1.2

Comment: please post code and logcat.